# Memory bounds on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++11, memory, time, cpu

I'm currently in the process of making an image processing program in C++ 11. The program aims to fill empty pixels in an image using an interpolation technique. The program runs fine and appears to do what was intended. My only problem is that it is taking forever to do so. During debugging I have noticed that the memory usage by Visual Studio 2015 looks like its capped at 314MB. The CPU usage also seems to be capped at around 30%. Since my program uses fairly demanding matrix operations I am wondering if this could be the reason that it is running so slow? Has anyone of you experienced this problem before? As it is now my program would be running for 2h before being completed, which is silly.

I hope I can get some answers on this

Comment: How many CPU cores do you have? E.g. if you have four, and your single-threaded program maxes one of them out, it will look like 25% CPU usage. Also, it seems you are measuring the performance of a debug build - that's unwise. Once you got your program to run correctly, make a release build.